# Problemas con manejo de arrays y objetos

Tags: nodejs

Resulta que tengo un metodo en mi controller que transforma un csv guardado como `json` en la base de datos, lo que hace es popular un array que luego se va a usar en react con la libreria `react-charts` el tema es que me esta iterando solo una fecha, si yo logueo `createdAt` antes del `for(properties in...` devuelve bien `22 y 23` que son los dos csv que tengo subidos. Pero si logueo la misma variable dentro del `for` tira siempre `23` y por eso me esta guardando solo datos como si fuera solo `23` no se a que se debe esto, ya que en teoría debería iterar todos los del `22` luego todos los del `23` y asi.

Este es el response que me trae la `DB`:

```js
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Chart details loading...",
    "start": "2019-09-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2019-09-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chart": [
        {
            "csv": [
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 4,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 12,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 1
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 4,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 3,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 1
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 6,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 3,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 6,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 2,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 5,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 3,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 5,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 2,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 2,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5d891e2344476f731dd0e088",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
            "id": "ijegef5es6",
            "report": "total_sessions",
            "type": "session",
            "company": "xxx",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "csv": [
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 5,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 4,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 1
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 2,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 5,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 3
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 4,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 1
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 3,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 4,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 7,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 1
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 1,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                },
                {
                    "Successful": 0,
                    "Failed": 0,
                    "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                    "In-Progress/Expired": 0
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5d891e4ec4094b7370075b3b",
            "id": "zogbqzi57q",
            "report": "total_sessions",
            "type": "session",
            "company": "xxx",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-23T19:34:38.250Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-09-23T19:34:38.250Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Luego lo que hago con este codigo es agrupar todos estos resultados de cada csv en uno solo, sumando los valores de cada property.

```js
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    var start = new Date(req.params.start);
    var end = new Date(req.params.end);
      
    Analytics.find({$and:[
            {company: req.params.company},
            {type: req.params.type},
            {report: req.params.report},
            {createdAt: {
                $gte: start,
                $lt: end
            }}
        ]}).sort({createdAt: 'asc'}).exec(function (err, charts) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: err
            });
        } else {           
            if (charts) {
               if(req.params.daily === "false"){
                var chartArr = [];
                charts.forEach(chart => {
                    var csv = {};
                    chart.csv.forEach(element => {
                        delete element['DateTime'];
                        for(val in element){
                            if(csv[val]){
                                csv[val]+=element[val];
                            }else{
                                csv[val] = element[val];
                            }
                        }    
                    }); 

                    let createdAt = new Date(chart.createdAt).getDate();
                    for (property in csv) {
                        var found = false;
                        for(var i = 0; i < chartArr.length; i++) {
                            if (chartArr[i].label == property) {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(found){
                            chartArr.forEach(item => {
                                if (item.label === property) {
                                    item.data.push([
                                        createdAt, csv[property]
                                    ]);
                                }   
                            });
                        }else{
                            chartArr.push({
                                label: property,
                                data: []
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
               }

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Chart details loading...',
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    chart: chartArr
                });
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Not found'
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Lo cual resulta en esta respuesta ya con las gráficas armadas digamos.

```js
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Chart details loading...",
    "start": "2019-09-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2019-09-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chart": [
        {
            "label": "Successful",
            "data": [
                [
                    23,
                    40
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Failed",
            "data": [
                [
                    23,
                    0
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "User Did Not Respond",
            "data": [
                [
                    23,
                    0
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "In-Progress/Expired",
            "data": [
                [
                    23,
                    6
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

El problema es que tal como se puede apreciar en la respuesta, solo se están populando los resultados del día 23, cuando en realidad también hay csv del día 22

Cualquier consulta estaré por aquí

Comment: Estás usando la fecha del chart, no la de los csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues lo que está pasando es que tu tienes un error en la lógica de programa. Específicamente en las líneas siguientes. Te explico a continuacíon y te pego una de las formas posibles de arreglarlo luego abajo.

```
charts.forEach(chart => {
    var csv = {};
    chart.csv.forEach(element => {
        delete element['DateTime'];
        for(val in element){
            if(csv[val]){
                csv[val]+=element[val];
            }else{
                csv[val] = element[val];
            }
        }    
    }); 

    let createdAt = new Date(chart.createdAt).getDate();

    // `charArr` está vacia cuando ejecutas este loop por primera vez, 
    // siendo así la varibale `found` no se cambiará a `true` hasta que
    // `charArr` pase a tener elementos.
    for (property in csv) {
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < chartArr.length; i++) {
            if (chartArr[i].label == property) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found){
            // Jamás entra acá cuando itera por el primero "chart".
            chartArr.forEach(item => {
                if (item.label === property) {
                    item.data.push([
                        createdAt, csv[property]
                    ]);
                }   
            });
        }else{
            // Sin embargo entrará acá por cada `property`, rellenando
            // chartArr. Por esta razón, cuando la iteración pasa al
            // segundo "chart", entonces sí se cambia el valor de la 
            // variable `found`, ejecutando así el bloque que está
            // adentro del `if` que está correcto.
            chartArr.push({
                label: property,
                data: []
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```js
var charts = [
    {
        "csv": [
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 4,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 12,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 1
            },
            {
                "Successful": 4,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 3,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 1
            },
            {
                "Successful": 6,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 3,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 6,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 2,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 5,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 3,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 5,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 2,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 2,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5d891e2344476f731dd0e088",
        "createdAt": "2019-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "id": "ijegef5es6",
        "report": "total_sessions",
        "type": "session",
        "company": "xxx",
        "updatedAt": "2019-09-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "csv": [
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 5,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 4,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 1
            },
            {
                "Successful": 2,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 5,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 3
            },
            {
                "Successful": 4,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 1
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 3,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 4,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 7,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 1
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 1,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            },
            {
                "Successful": 0,
                "Failed": 0,
                "User Did Not Respond": 0,
                "In-Progress/Expired": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5d891e4ec4094b7370075b3b",
        "id": "zogbqzi57q",
        "report": "total_sessions",
        "type": "session",
        "company": "xxx",
        "createdAt": "2019-09-23T19:34:38.250Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-09-23T19:34:38.250Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
];

var chartArr = [];
charts.forEach(chart => {
    var csv = {};
    chart.csv.forEach(element => {
        delete element['DateTime'];
        for(val in element){
            if(csv[val]){
                csv[val]+=element[val];
            }else{
                csv[val] = element[val];
            }
        }
    });
    let createdAt = new Date(chart.createdAt).getDate();
    for (property in csv) {
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < chartArr.length; i++) {
            if (chartArr[i].label == property) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            chartArr.push({
                label: property,
                data: []
            });
        }

        chartArr.forEach(item => {
            if (item.label === property) {
                item.data.push([
                    createdAt, csv[property]
                ]);
            }
        });
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(chartArr, undefined, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

ya revisando un poco más a fondo veo que no estás revisando el arreglo donde pones las fechas para hacer un match completo (sólo buscas el label), por eso no encuentras bien el elemento a insertar en la última parte, además no estás grabando datos si no se encuentra el elemento, lo modifiqué un poco pero al final me quedó así:

```
    var csvName;
    for (csvName in csv) {
      var found = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < chartArr.length; i++) {
        if (
          (chartArr[i].label === csvName) &
          !existDate(createdAt, chartArr[i].data)
        ) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        chartArr.forEach(item => {
          if (item.label === csvName) {
            //console.log(createdAtx, csvName)
            item.data.push([createdAt, csv[csvName]]);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("not found");
        chartArr.push({
          label: csvName,
          data: [[createdAt, csv[csvName]]]
        });
      }
    }
```

y la función de búsqueda auxiliar la dejé así:

```
function existDate(date, datos = []) {
  datos.forEach(data => {
    console.log("in exist", date, data[0]);
    if (data[0] === date) return true;
  });
  return false;
}
```

te recomiendo separar las funciones que realizas dentro del procedimiento para establecer que se pueda ver tu estrategia de un vistazo, y luego poder pasar a detalles de implementación, y no como lo tienes en código corrido. 
También si ya estás usando forEach síguelo usando y no te pases al for(), y así mantener una estética del código.

Otro punto a revisar es la región que traen las fechas, en unas tienen una cierta area de UTC y otras que se ven en tu ejemplo están en otra región. Esto puede traerte datos "extraños" porque no está correctamente alineada la región dentro del sistema.